# Can I find text that's "close" to some query with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my DB called `text`. It will have something like `this is an example of lite coin`. I want to query this for `litecoin` and things that are close (like `lite coin`). Is there some way to do this generically as I will have multiple queries. Maybe something with a max Levenshtein distance?

Comment: Check out [Postgres Full Text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/textsearch.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 on the trigram suggestion. Trigrams in Postgres are *excellent* and, for sure, indexible. Depending on the index option you choose (GIN or GiST), you get access to different operators. If I remember correctly off the top of my head, GiST gives you distance tolerances for the words, and lets you search for them in order. You can specify the number of words expected between two searches words, and more. (If I'm remembering correctly.) Both GIN and GiST are worth experimenting with.

Levenshtein compares two specific strings, so it doesn't lend itself to indexing. What would you index? The comparison string is unknown in advance. You could index every string by every string in a column and, apart from the O(aaaargh!) complexity, you still might not have unything like your search string in the index.

Tip: If you must use Levenshtein, and it is pretty great where it's useful, you *can* eliminate many rows from your comparison cheaply. If you've got a 10 character search string and want strings only with a distance of 2, you can eliminate shorter and longer strings from consideration without fear of losing any matches.

You might find that you want to apply Levenshtein (or Jaccard, etc.) to possible matches found by the trigrams. But, honestly, Levenshtein is, by nature, biased towards strings in the same order. That's okay for lite coin/light coin/litecoin, but not helpful when the words can be in any order, like with first and last name, much address data, and many, many phrase-like searches.

The other thing to consider, depending on your range of queries, are full text searches with tsvectors. These are also indexable, and also support a range of operators.

Comment: How, exactly, would I use the trigram in a query?

Comment: Start with the Fine Documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html There are also lots of articles with examples out there, which are likely an easier way to get started. Here's one, but there are many others.: https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-make-text-searches-in-postgresql-faster-with-trigram-similarity

Answer (score 4):

There is a [core extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html) to PostgreSQL which implements the Levenshtein distance.  For strings of very unequal length, as in your example, the distance will of necessity be large.  So you would have to implement some normalization method, unless all phrases being searched within are the same length.

I don't think Levenshtein is indexable.  You could instead look into [trigram distance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), which is indexable.